# SMTP NodeMailer sends emails in localhost but not on production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I'm trying to send user verification emails after sign ups.

The app is built using Node.JS and JavaScript, and I'm using `SMTP` and `Nodemailer` NPM Module to send the emails.

The code below works fine and sends email correctly when testing locally in 'localhost' on my PC, but won't work when uploaded on the production server.

I've contacted my web host and they say the configurations are set correctly.

The code gives the error:

```json
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 198.xx.xxx.xxx
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '198.xx.xxx.xxx',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

And again the code sends emails fine when running locally on my PC.

Could you please help me identify the issue with this code?

Thanks in advance!

```js
const sendMsg = async (receiver, title, msg) => {

    // Define configurations for the SMTP Server.
    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
       host: "mail.privateemail.com",
       secure: true,
       port: 465, 
       auth: {
            user: "myxxxxx@company.com",
            pass: "mypassword"
        }
    });

    // Define message parameters
    var mailOptions={
        from: "My Company <myxxxxx@company.com>",
        to : receiver,
        subject : title,
        text : "",
        html : msg 
    }

    // Send email to client
    var mailSent = await smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then((response) => {return true;})
    .catch(err => { console.log(err); return false;});

    return mailSent
};
```

Comment: here's a *troubleshooting* idea ... `.catch(err => {return false;});` ... `err` may have some useful content

Comment: also, is the code *identical* locally and on production? or are there some minor tweaks, like the host, for example

Comment: You’ve confirmed that your web host allows outbound connections on port 465 through their firewall?

Comment: have you confirmed `mail.privateemail.com` accepts mail from "production server"?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I get a couldn't reach error. Sorry to ask, but would this code send emails rightly during localhost testing if my web host does not allow outbound connections on port 465 through their firewall?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes the code is identical.

Comment: @BrettDonald Sorry to ask, but would this code send emails rightly during localhost testing if my web host does not allow outbound connections on port 465 through their firewall?

Comment: When running on localhost, the code is using *your* internet connection (provided by your ISP) to send mail on port 465. When the code is running on your production server, the code is using the internet connection available to the server, managed by your web host. Two different connections, two different security setups. Looks like your ISP allows outbound connections on port 465, but your web host does not (by default).

Comment: @BrettDonald Yes Brett, this was exactly the reason. But my web host opened the port and the code works fine now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The above code works fine.

I had to contact my webhost to ask them to open port 465.

I didn't know the code will work fine during localhost testing, even if port 465 is closed on the production server.

That said, my webhost opened port 465 on the server and the code now sends emails fine even on the production server.